# VSCode: Insert suggestion from debug console with Enter instead of tab on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I run VSCode on my mac and Ubuntu machines and sync settings between them. However, I am seeing a different behavior between the machines. On my mac, I can insert a suggestion by pressing `enter`. [image: insert]

But on Ubuntu, I have to use `tab`. I would like to use `enter` for both. I have the setting `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart"` on both machines. I tried changing this to `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"` but this had no effect. Is there something that I'm failing to sync? How can I accept the suggestion with `enter` on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method1: Go to `Keyboard shortcuts` then set `acceptSelectedSuggestion` to `Enter`.

Method2: Open `keybindings.json` and replace `tab` with `enter` as follows:

````
    { "key": "enter",
      "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
}```
````